# Exception: Correlation failed. Unknown location Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, google-authentication

All of a sudden Google Authentication does not work with my ASP.NET Core 3.1 App

```
  services.AddAuthentication()
                    .AddGoogle(opts =>
                {
                    opts.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("GoogleLogin").GetSection("ClientId").Value;
                    opts.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("GoogleLogin").GetSection("ClientSecret").Value;
                    opts.Events = new OAuthEvents
                    {
                        OnCreatingTicket = context =>
                        {
                            var profileUrl = context.User.GetProperty("picture").ToString();
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", profileUrl));
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    };
                });
```

Comment: Found the solution: Use https

Comment: As an aside, you should use `Task.CompletedTask` instead of `Task.FromResult(0)`.